# How to search case sensitive in a case insensitive index

Tags: sql, oracle, case-sensitive, oracle-text

I have to query with over 100 words (case insensitive) that are stored in a separate table.

```
Select a_id, text from xy
inner join keywords kw on contains(xy.text, kw.word)>0
```

This works fine. But now I have one keyword that has to be queried case sensitive.

Does somebody know how to do that without creating a case sensitive index and query that keyword separately? Is it maybe possible to ignore a keyword, let's say 'us', and only create the index with the keyword in capital letters ('US').

I tried it with adding 'us' to the stopwords but it didn't worked out.

Comment: Use `UPPER` or `LOWER` on both columns and create a function-based index, since regular index will be skipped.

Comment: I think this will not work with oracle text.

Comment: If you are on 11g or above, you can add a virtual column generated always as `UPPER` of the column and use them.

Comment: And if you are looking for case insensitive search, have a look at http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/oracle-case-insensitive-sorts-compares/

Answer (score 0):

Add a column `case_sensitive char(1) -- Y/N` to the `keywords` table, then:

```
select a_id, text
from xy
join keywords kw on contains(xy.text, kw.word) > 0
  and (kw.case_sensitive = 'N' or instr(xy.text, kw.word) > 0)
```

The index will still be used, but there is an additional requirement for case sensitive keywords that the keyword must appear verbatim in the text.